# Trying to back up CentOS using the "dd" command

Tags: image, backup, dd

I'd like to back up a SSD which I'm using for CentOS. Trying to learn dd. My drive is a fairly simple GPT partition of 120GB.

1. I run "dd" to copy the image of sda to a USB stick sdd1:

[root@localhost ~]# dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror status=progress bs=64k of=/dev/sdd1
120029118464 bytes (120 GB, 112 GiB) copied, 30810 s, 3.9 MB/s
1831575+1 records in
1831576+0 records out
120034164736 bytes (120 GB, 112 GiB) copied, 30810.8 s, 3.9 MB/s

2. But then when I examine the USB stick, there is nothing to be seen on it and I see no way to mount it

[this is what appears under the Disks command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGeIN.png)

---

Question is:
How do I access the image?

(As a side note, I read a claim that the dd command is like the IBM JCL statement of the same name. I was a mainframe programmer. The IBM DD command is often still called a "DD Card". It doesn't copy files. It just joins your file declaration in your program to some external file. To copy a file the old skool way is to use IEBGENER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if=/dev/sda` Is cloning the entire disk and `of=/dev/sdd1` Is writing to a partition. Which doesn't make much sense.

You may want to clone the entire disk onto another disk

```
dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror status=progress bs=64k of=/dev/sdd
```

Or better yet clone to an compressed image

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip  > /sda.img.gz
```

And restore like so

```
gzip -d /sda.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda
```